# PSPICE Simulation of Cascode Amplifier Not Working

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, design

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting the following "floating node" errors. I have fiddled around with the resistors to see if it affects anything, so these are not the actual values. I have also read a number of post on PSPICE "floating node" errors, but nothing has helped so far. Everything seems to be grounded... I just want to get rid of the simulation errors for now. Thank you.

Here is the schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Here are the errors:

[image: Errors]

Comment: On a different note.  This circuit doesn't look like a cascode amplifier.  In a [cascode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode), the drain of one MOSFET is connected to the source of another.

Comment: @NickAlexeev More of a cascade than a cascode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple problem with an equally simple fix. Your entire circuit is floating. You need to use this for GND:

[image]

Edit: Node 0 is the internal reference in SPICE for all voltages, and the ground symbol with the graphic '0' is connected to it. Every node in your circuit **must** have a DC path  to node 0 (even if that path is a 100G ohm resistor). The ground symbols without the 0 are simply connected to all the other similar symbols with the same net name (GND or GND_POWER typically). You could also edit the node name for the symbol you used from GND to 0, but I think it's better to use the provided symbol.

Comment: What a simply/stupid problem. I hadn't considered the differences between grounds... can you please round out your impressive answer by mentioning a few differences between the grounds that are found in PSPICE... such as the one I originally tried to use (no 0), the one you suggested (w/ 0), and any other one you feel is important/relevant. It will go a long way. If you want, that is :)